# Correr proyecto flutter en en vim con git-bash con plugin vim-flutter

Tags: flutter, vim, git-bash

Estoy intentando correr un proyecto Flutter en vim con ayuda del plugin [vim-flutter](https://github.com/thosakwe/vim-flutter#vim-flutter) utilizando la consola de Git Bash en windows.

Cuando utilizo el comando `:FlutterRun` que ejecuta `flutter run` desde la aplicación GVIM que es la que viene cuando instalo vim funciona correctamente. Pero, cuando lo ejecuto desde la terminal Git-Bash me devuleve el siguiete error:

> Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
> This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.

ya probé correr el comando estando en diferentes archivos pero en ninguno funciona. Donde debo correr el archivo para que funcione en git bash tal como lo hace en gvim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un error de despistado, pero lo dejo por si en el futuro ayuda a alguien con el mismo despiste:

En mi caso lo que estaba haciendo era situarme en la carpeta donde guardo todos mis proyectos (llamémosla **ProjectsDir**) y ejecutar el comando `vim nombreDelProyecto`. Esto hacía que el comando `:FlutterRun` se ejecutara desde **ProjectsDir**.

Lo que hay que hacer es situarse dentro de nuestro proyecto y hacer el vim desde dentro. (Por ejemplo `vim lib`) y ya desde dentro ejecutar el `:FlutterRun`